# Informality in addressing God

Tags: speech-talking, chilul-kidush-hashem

In Hebrew or English, people are addressed as "you". But in many other languages, such as French or Italian, there is a formal way to address people (vous, lei) and an informal way (tu, tu).  You only use the second with an equal that you have known for some time, or with family and close friends, and by mutual consent.

Now, in these languages, God is always addressed in the informal way. I always wondered why. One would think respect would dictate the formal address. Do our commentators address this point?

Comment: Informal is usually not followed by an honorific. However, if someone were to say “you, my master” it would not be informal since it’s followed by an honorable description.

Comment: "You, my master" in the informal would be an impossibility in these languages. Unutterable.

Comment: This sounds more like a question for a linguistics SE. Why would our commentators deal with other languages?

Comment: Many of them spoke and used these other languages in their commentaries.  Surely they had an opinion on the matter.  Rashi even incorporated French in his comments.

Comment: European UO Jews still keep that formality and rabbis are addressed in second person plural "אתם" or third person "הוא" or "הרב". For example, "האם הרב יכול לבוא?" or "תוכלו בבקשה לבוא?".

Comment: You can't put Hebrew and English in one sentence "in those languages". Those are absolutely different languages with different roots. THerefore there will be different reasons. Please rephrase the question.

Comment: In Hebrew, after David or all prophets consistently used the second person single when addressing God, we do not change the tradition "אַתָּה־הוּא ה"א אֲשֶׁר בָּחַרְתָּ בְּאַבְרָם"

Comment: After Rabbis set the standard phrasing of all Jewish prayers, we can't dare to change.

Comment: We are supposed to feel close to G-d, and the formal "you" would create more distance than the informal one (I assume, I don't know firsthand the mindset involved in formal vs informal address). In fact, I heard once that referring to parents in the third person is a mistake that causes extraneous distance between parents and children, and only comes from the fact that in Yiddish, third person was the "formal" way of addressing someone and it was "unheard of" to address a parent in second person. But G-d was always addressed in second person still.